# Road Intersection [Geometry nodes]

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'd like to do a road interection system in Geometry nodes. Any idea how to get intersecting lines. Like on Image below.
[image]
[image]

Comment: I think the most reasonable solution is to hand-craft (manually model) intersections and put them at joints…

Comment: I need a more procedural solution because all intersections are different and I'm to lazy to fix them... Thanks for comment.